homeomorphism between topological manifolds. Invariance of domain.
I am studying topological manifold with boundaries (no smooth structure added to it yet) and I am confused about a definition and what apparently seemed to be a straightforward exercise.
Firstly, my teacher's definition for an interior (resp. boundary) point, $p$, is that there exists a neighbourhood containing $p$ homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$/ ($\mathbb H^n$). It says nothing about the openness of such a neighbourhood. I found both statements in the literature, some authors demand the neighbourhood to be open and some don't. Does this really matter for the definition? Can't I just argue that any neighbourhood of a point contains an open subset that also contains said point and be done with it?
Secondly, the exercise states that given two topological 2-manifolds with boundary $M$ and $N$ and a homeomorphism $f:M\rightarrow N$, any interior (resp. boundary) point $p \in M$ is mapped to an interior (resp. boundary) point $f(p) \in N$. That is, $int(M)\cong int(N)$ (resp. $\partial M\cong \partial N$).
My teacher's answer, which was my first attempt, goes like this:
Let $p \in int(M)$, then there exists $U\subset M$ and an open subset $V\subset \mathbb R^2$ such that $ U\cong V$. Let $\phi:U\rightarrow V$ be a homeomorphism and consider the map $\phi\circ f^{-1}|_{f(U)}:f(U)\rightarrow V$ that is a homeomorphism by composition. Then $f(U)$ is a neighbourhood o $f(p)$ homomeorphic to the open $V\subset\mathbb R^2$ so $f(int(M))\subset int(N)$. We would get the inverse inclusion by symmetry and be done.
At first, I was quite happy to see that my proof agreed with the teacher's answer but was feeling uneasy about it. I started thinking about the openness of the neighbourhood of the interior point definition and looking into the literature but couldn't convince myself of any flaw in my teacher's argument. Then I tried to prove it in another way arguing that if any interior point was mapped to a boundary point, we would get a contradiction. To do so, I must apply the invariance of domain theorem ( or so I think) and I couldn't help but wondering why it wasn't necessary to use the theorem for my first proof (and teacher's answer). I still feel uneasy about it but cannot grasp where the "handwaving" of my first answer comes from.
Would you guys have any idea where my proof is actually incomplete? or maybe it is fine and I might be overthinking it?
Thank you very much in advance.

It does not matter in general that you require open neighbourhood to be open or not since they always contain an open set containing your bas point. Your proof is ok and both statements are equivalent so either way to present it is fine (in the non open case you naturally get an open neighbourhood. Now you could have in some very particular cases trouble without assuming the AoC but this is very unlikely (I can’t think of a situation where this could happen)).

Also your proof  is perfectly valid And my comment on the AoC is irrelevant


The definition of boundary point is incomplete. You need the homeomorphism between the neighborhood of $p$ and the open set of $\mathbb{H}^n$ to map $p$ to a point of $\partial\mathbb{H}^n$. Otherwise, every point would be a boundary point.

Yes, if there is a neighborhood of $p$ homeomorphic to an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it contains an open neighborhood of $p$, which is homeomorphic to an open subset of $U$ (and that is also an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$). The case of boundary points is similar.

In fact, if $M$ is an $n$-manifold, $p\in N\subseteq M$ is a neighborhood and $N\cong U$ with $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ open, then $U\cong N\subseteq M$ is a continuous injection between $n$-manifolds, so invariance of domain implies that it is an open map, i.e. the neighborhood $N$ is a posteriori itself open. There is a similar statement for boundary points (but it's slightly subtler to prove).

Yes, the given argument is correct. Also, the assumption that $M,N$ are $2$-manifolds (as opposed to manifolds of arbitrary dimension) is completely irrelevant.

The reason your argument by contradiction does not work so easily is because it assumes that a point cannot be both an interior point and a boundary point at once. This is true, but requires invariance of domain. However, you do not need to know that dichotomy holds in order to prove that a homeomorphism preserves interior and boundary points respectively.



Thank you very much for your insightful answer, it was really helpful and completely solved my doubts.
